# Struct definition Function of type Static

Tags: c

I came across the below line in one of the code:

```
static DATA_BLOCK_SOX_s data_blockSox = {.header.uniqueId = DATA_BLOCK_ID_SOX};
```

I want to know what form of Syntax is this and what is exactly happening here
Thanks

Comment: Which language are you talking about? C or C#? Those two are very different

Comment: It's almost a designated initializer in C; I don't think the nested dots are valid, though.  I dunno whether it is valid C#.

Comment: You might want to read up on how C99 struct initialization can be done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's not valid C#. C# would have `{ header = new { uniqueId = DATA_BLOCK_ID_SOX} };`

Comment: @Joshua: Presumably why Jonathan said "almost."

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it looks like chaining designators *is* valid in C (C17 6.7.9/1,17).  I never fully understood paragraph 17 before, myself (nor studied the grammar in paragraph 1 in sufficient detail), but this example provided an "Aha!" moment for me.

Comment: The example being (potentially) valid C, but not valid C#, I take the code to in fact be C code. I have edited the tags appropriately.  I presume that the OP already knows what language it is, such that discerning that was not intended to be part of the question.

Comment: See [What does the static keyword do in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285050)

Comment: @JohnBollinger However from what I remember, gcc goes bananas with various false warnings whenever you try to do more intricate stuff with designated initializers. Used to be like that at least ([see this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194935/wmissing-field-initializer-when-using-designated-initializers)), they might have fixed it by now.

Comment: @JohnBollinger —yes, I agree; the syntax does allow for chained designators.  So it is (could be) a valid C99 or later designated initializer if the structure of the type makes the designated element valid.  We can assume it is valid if the fragment is from working code.  I wasn't on my computer when I wrote the comment.  I'm glad I prevaricated.

Comment: I can believe that, @Lundin, but my experiments just now suggest that GCC got that worked out by version 8.5.

Answer (score 2):

That's a C struct initializer with named fields ([designated initializers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9)).

```
static DATA_BLOCK_SOX_s data_blockSox = {.header.uniqueId = DATA_BLOCK_ID_SOX};
```

Creates a `DATA_BLOCK_SOX_s` in load-time allocated storage called `data_blockSox` scoped to this file, initializing all fields to binary zero except for `header.uniqueId` (where `header` is clearly a nested `struct` or `union`) which is initialized to `DATA_BLOCK_ID_SOX`.

I have used indentation to infer file scope. That could be incorrect. If it's inside a function it should be indented, but as we know, the compiler doesn't care.

In the unlikely case that you actually care about systems for which NULL is not binary zero, it has been pointed out that pointer fields should be initialized to NULL even on systems that have NULL as not binary zero. I have only ever seen that spec not followed.

Comment: Re “initializing all fields to binary zero”: Per C 6.7.9 10 (possibly by way of 6.7.9 13), the implicitly initialized elements will be initialized to zero values for arithmetic types, null pointers for pointer types, and recursively so for aggregates. This is not equivalent to initializing all fields to binary zero. Padding bytes in structures and unions may be non-zero, padding bits in arithmetic types may be non-zero, and the representation of a null pointer might be non-zero.

Comment: `static` affects linkage and storage duration, not scope. Any identifier declared with `static` is visible in the same places it would be if declared in the same place except without `static`; the scope of the declaration remains unchanged. At file scope, using `static` will give the identifier internal linkage instead of external. In block scope, using `static` has no effect on linkage.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like C99. And should be something like:

```
struct Point {int x, y;}; // This would be the stand-in for DATA_BLOCK_SOX_s
typedef struct Point Point;

static Point point = { .y = 10, .x = 5 }; // here the members y and x get their values
```

In your case there is a nested struct called `header`. This as a member calles `uniqueId`.